# Convert chain in array and remove duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of chain:

> $ListBoss = 1,6,3,1,10,11,

I want to make a array for each value and remove the duplicates.

How can I proceed please ?

Do I need to use the explode function ?

Comment: You can **proceed** by showing us, what you have tried.

Comment: Look into php's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) (on `','`, as it looks to be the separator here) to create an array from your string, then [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to extract only unique values:

```
$str = '1,6,3,1,10,11';
$arr = array_unique(explode(',', $str));
```

---

Can't help wondering, though, where's that string coming from, and isn't it (yet another) denormalized value stored in DB.